# I'm new to Spring, The scheduled task is not saving data to the database, @Scheduled not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to auto run and save data to DB every 5 minutes. I tried to use Scheduled Spring framework. In the console I could see that the task is running but not saved in the database.

```
@Override
public Single<xModel> testScheduled(@NonNull String someName, @NonNull String someType) {
  log.info("entering testScheduled, someName = {}, someType = {}", someName, someType);
  ReadPoint readPoint = readPointRepository.findById(someName).orElseThrow();
  String configurationName = Try.of(() -> readType.valueOf(readPoint.getType()))
    .orElse(Try.success(readType.DEFAULT))
    .map(readType::getConfigurationName)
    .get();
    log.info("test={}", readPoint);
  var inv = invClient
    .epcInv(readPoint.getReadIp(), 
readPoint.getConfiguration().getAnte(),
Optional.of(configurationName), Optional.empty())
    .map(pcs -> pcs.stream()
    .map(pce -> new yModel(pce, getRealDeno(pce)))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
    .map(chips -> new xModel(someType, someName, chips))
    .doOnSuccess(mModel -> upsert(mModel));
  return inv;
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void schetestsee() {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Wonderful Task executed at "+ new Date());
  String someName = "testsomething";
  String someType = "SCHEDULED";
  log.info("EnteringSchedutestsee");
  this.testScheduled(someName, someType);
}
```

I'm trying to do in the same class.

Comment: I would recommend either using a debugger or adding more logs, in order to know at which step of the routine the execution is getting stuck. Adding a `try/catch` block and putting the exception on the log (including the stack trace) would help you a lot; if some errror is happening, the stack trace will tell you the exact line where it happened.

Comment: Try adding @EnableScheduling annotation above main class.

Comment: @Vishal Jamdade Yes, I added the EnableScheduling annotation. But it does not work. I can see the logs in the console but nothing is being saved to the database.

Comment: You are doing reactive programming but aren't subscribing to any of it, so you only define the reactive stream but don't do anything with it. You should have something like `this.testScheduled(someName, someType).subscribe()`.